# Methods for affecting properties vs returning a value

Tags: php

New to the community and wondering if there is any best-practice guidance on approach to OOP methods?

Assuming that code re-use is not necessary (instantiation/one-time routines etc.), should private methods assign property values themselves, or rather return a value to be assigned by the invoking method?

Consider the following PHP example:

```
<?php

class MyClass1
{

    private $foo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setFoo();
    }

    private function setFoo()
    {

        // no params
        // returns void

        $this->foo = 6;

    }

}


class MyClass2
{

    private $foo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foo = $this->setFoo();
    }

    private function setFoo()
    {

        // no params
        // returns value

        return 6;

    }

}


class MyClass3
{

    private $foo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foo = $this->setFoo(3);
    }

    private function setFoo( $val )
    {

        // accepts param
        // returns value

        return $val;

    }

}

?>
```

Are there any significant reasons for/against the *MyClass1* approach?

i.e. Built with methods which are procedural and access/assign to properties directly, rather than accepting parameters and returning a value (so essentially all DocBlocks contain *@return void*)

Hope this makes sense - mainly curious :)

Many thanks,

Comment: `setFoo` should **set** foo to some passed value. Now it acts as getter. Please invest time in learning how to use setters and getters. http://thisinterestsme.com/php-getters-and-setters/

Comment: You can define the default value directly: `private $foo = 6;` ... you should probably just keep reading http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: Class2 doesn't make sense. You're basically using 6 as a constant there, so you might as well make it a constant and not have a method at all. If you make it a method, don't call it `setFoo` if it doesn't set foo. Class1 is the better. In real life scenarios this setter would often be somehow exposed to the outside world, and could be invoked multple times. If you're only calling it from the constructor, you might as well set the property right away in the constructor, or even specify the value in the property declaration itself.

Comment: Many thanks for the responses! The code was only an example - of course "set" should not be used to name a getter method(!), I only used it to retain consistency. I'm also aware that values can be assigned at instantiation-time, effectively acting as constants. Perhaps it was a poor example... My main enquiry is regarding best practice - is it acceptable to compose a class entirely of methods which set property values procedurally - e.g. "set foo1; set foo2; set foo3; return nothing" - i.e. not invoke any methods which themselves return a value. @GolezTrol I'll err on the side of Class1 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a much more eloquent (albeit Java-oriented) [thread](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/316407/what-style-is-better-instance-variable-vs-return-value-in-java) with clearer terminology than I have managed!

**TL;DR**

Private methods as **procedures** (change in object state, no return value)

- *Pros*: Plays to OOP strengths (encapsulation / communication between private methods)
- *Cons*: Harder to scale (mutation of same instance variable by multiple methods implicates flow control)

Private methods as **functions** (object state does not change, value is returned)

- *Pros*: Greater clarity around program flow
- *Cons*: Potential for unintentional hidden side-effects (nature of OOP cannot guarantee that mutations are completely avoided - relies upon assumptions/conditionals to be fully-documented)